# Dealing with drift-over-time in rigid object tracking?

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, object-detection, drift

I'm tracking a rigid object that can move slowly or stand still for long periods of time (72 hours). A drawback of most approaches is the error accumulation over time resulting in a drift away from the object.

Is there a standard method to avoid this? The object can and will move/rotate in 3 dimensions.

I'm using SIFT+RANSAC type matching at the moment to find corner points then matching them on the assumption that some kind of constellation matching would eliminate drift.

Comment: Do you know what the object looks like ahead of time?

Comment: No. A "good" nearby object with lots of corners to track is selected by the user when the program starts. At that point the front of the object is known. So drift when rotating is probably unvaoidable since we dont know for sure what other sides look like. But need to eliminate it entirely when still.

Comment: What is introducing the drift? Corner tracking should be very stable.

Comment: maybe the quality of the camera isn't that good and the camera noise is initroducing the drift. Or low lighting conditions.

Comment: Drift in the object model introduces drift in where the object is detected. The individual corners cannot drift; that's why I thought something starting with corner to be a good approach. A corner can occasionally be missed entirely for a frame or 2 though. If you'd like to recommend a corner tracking algorithm please do; but I can already do that; albeit crudely. If you know a reliable algorithm for tracking an object based on corners, tell me it. I didn't mention corner detection in the original question because any approach that works is fine. I just started with this one.

Comment: The camera/lighting isn't that good but that's beside the point; I'm trying with an easier camera 1st probably. The object is moving around continually even while "still" but assuming the tracker works; not much, and not changing scale or rotating.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean now. If the camera is still, your target object's projection on the camera should always be at the same aproximate 2d coordinates if the object is still. In your first frame, remember the 2d coordinates of the projection. For the rest of the frames create a low pass filter over the (current 2d coordinates - initial first frame coordinates) over time to filter out small errors in position. After a certain threshold, consider the object moved.

Comment: How to you tell if a reference object is in view? Obviously if i have it "in view" that means i know its position, therefore i don't need to DO any calculations at that point. I want to know if there is a tracking method that has zero drift over time when the object is still, works on rigid objects, and can handle 3d rotation (small drift during rotation is probably unavoidable)

Comment: The model for determining if "it" is in view will generally change over time. So the definition of "it" will change and the tracker will drift.

Comment: You're on the right track. The obvious solution: Don't update the model; so there is no drift. If the difference between model and current img goes above some threshold only, then update. But the difference at this point must still be small enough we can still track the object accurately; or we're too late. That's what you said boils down to as well I think, and its a reasonable approach. My question was basically if anyone knows of a standard way of doing this.